# Position of Adverb of manner before or after preposition

Tags: adverbs

> I will tell a story **slowly** to you.
>   I will tell a story to you **slowly**.

Which one of the above sentences is correct.

Comment: It’s a matter of style as long as the meaning is clear.

Comment: Adverbs follow many different rules for where they go, depending on the structure and also the words involved. There are almost always several equally grammatical options, and the speaker chooses whatever sounds best to them.

Comment: You missed a couple of variations: (1) *I will **slowly** tell a story to you.* (2) ***Slowly***, *I will tell a story to you.*